# Quick, intermittent buzzing sound and freezing

Tags: windows, audio, cpu, freeze, gpu

I've recently been having this issue with my desktop PC. When I'm playing games, or watching videos, every now and then I hear a buzzing noise from my headphones and the video/game freezes for a split second, then resumes normally. It's very short, and it happens without any pattern.

Here are my specs:

- Processor: Intel Core i7 3770K @ 3.50 GHz
- Memory: 8 GB DDR3
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 670
- OS: Windows 7 64-bit

At first, I thought this might be an issue with my GPU overheating. I have been running temperature monitoring, and it never goes over 70C when I run games at highest settings. I have tested by reducing graphic settings, and it still happened when GPU was running at a steady 40C-50C. And then it started happening when I was watching movies (GPU at 30C), which has me thinking that it might not be related to GPU.

I have been checking my CPU temperatures and they seem fine as well. Hovering between 30C and 40C.

Besides temperature, I don't know what else could be causing this. Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling audio and video drivers and also clean your system. If problem persist make sure every connectors are setup right. Also did you try oovercloaking your PC?
Start by updating drivers, cleaning pc and reinstalling your game.

Comment: I updated my graphics drivers. I'll update the audio drivers. I never overclocked my PC, and I clean up the interior from dust every two weeks, and as I mentioned in the question, the problem isn't with the game, it happens during video playback too.